# How can I invalidate session in resource listener's 'onDisconnect' event?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, atmosphere

I tried to invoke session.invalidate() in AtmosphereResource's onDisconnect, but the session instance is not HttpServletSession object, it is instance of FakeHttpSession and without invalidate method implementation.

The code goes here:

```
@Override
public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
    super.onDisconnect(event);
    AtmosphereResource res = event.getResource();
    broadcaster.removeResource(res);
    HttpSession session = res.getRequest().getSession(false);
    if (session != null) session.invalidate();  // Can't invalidate the session.
}
```

How can I invalidate session in this place.

Comment: which atmosphere version do you use ? the session's code has been re-written in 1.0.

Comment: The atmosphere version is 1.1.0.RC2.

Comment: Could you try with a new version (1.1.0-beta3 for example). Some bugs has been resolved (ex https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/commit/aad412feecd5af83643455603586118abd49a7f3)

Comment: I have changed the version to 2.0.0.RC1, FakeHttpSession's invalidate method was filled finally.

Comment: It seems you have figured out a way. Could you please answer it yourself. Thanks